# Match string with a dataframe in R

Tags: r, match

I have a 2 dataframes say `title` and `names` which contain the data like

```
> title
          Name           corrected_Name
1         Ind               India
2         USA               United States
3         UK                United Kingdom
4         Eng               England
5         Aus               Australia
6         Nzl               NewZealand
7         UAE               Arab
8         Byn Mnch          Bayern Munich
```

and

```
> names
1         Clark
2         Micheal USA
3         Sara Eng
4         Laurie Lance
5         Vivek Ind
6         Eric byn mnch
```

I want to match if any word in a string of `names` dataframe matches with any entry of `title` and if yes then put the corrected value in place of that and save it in a dataframe `corrected`
i.e.

```
> corrected
1       Clark
2       Micheal United States
3       Sara England
4       Laurie Lance
5       Vivek India
6       Eric Bayern Munich
```

I have tried using `grep` and `pmatch` to find the match but they match only if the whole string is in the dataframe

```
grep(title$Name, names)
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could separate your entries in `names` to individual words by using `strsplit(names, ' ')` and then test these individually.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't use strsplit (please check the edited question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My general strategy is to split the names from the `names` data frame by space, and then to use the second part to join to the `title` data frame.

```
# obtain the first name as the first word
names$first <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(names$name), " "),
                      function(x) {
                         return(x[1])
                      })

# obtain the country abbreviation as the second word
names$country <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(names$name), " "),
                        function(x) {
                           return(x[2])
                        })

# join 'names' and `title' using the abbreviation
names <- merge(names, title, by.x = "country", by.y = "Name", all.x=TRUE)

# convert 'corrected_Name' to character and identify non matches
names$corrected_Name <- as.character(names$corrected_Name)
index <- is.na(names$corrected_Name)
names$corrected <- as.character(names$name)

# compute 'corrected' column as paste of first and 'corrected_Name',
# if the latter exists (and if not default to the original 'name' column)
names$corrected[!index] <- paste(names$first[!index],
                                 names$corrected_Name[!index])
```

Here is the output from the above script:

```
> names[,c("name", "corrected")]
          name             corrected
1     Sara Eng          Sara England
2    Vivek Ind           Vivek India
3 Laurie Lance          Laurie Lance
4  Micheal USA Micheal United States
5        Clark                 Clark
```

Note that this solution is robust to the scenario where a name has two parts (e.g. `Laurie Lance`), because the last name will not map to a country.  The only case where this would fail is if someone's last name happened to coincide with a country's abbreviation.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't use strsplit as it would split laurie and lance as well (please check the edited question)

Comment: No...my solution will still work because `Lance` would not map to any actual country.  The only instance where my code would fail would be if someone's last name were coincidentally also a country's abbreviation.

Comment: Yes, it works absolutely fine but in one case like if a entry of title name is `Eng Swed` and the corrected name is `england sweden`  and someone's name is like `Tom Eng swed` then it won't give the correct result otherwise it works perfect

Comment: With regard to these edge cases, do you expect them to occur?  In such a case, you should rethink how you store the person's country abbreviation in such a way that it doesn't get confused with the last name.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that it is just sample data I am dealing with company names like title name may be `pvt ltd` with the corrected name of `private limited` and a company's name can be `xyz pvt ltd` and i need it as `xyz private limited`

Comment: @Looper you should update your question to include such cases then.

Comment: @Looper I won't modify my answer.  Instead, you should take one of the answers already given and see if you can apply it for multiple matches to a given name.

Comment: Got the solution of my problem!! Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` as well

```
i1 <- match(sub("\\S+\\s+", "", df2$names), df1$Name)
nm1 <- df1$corrected_Name[i1]
i2 <- !is.na(nm1)
df2$names[i2] <- paste(sub('\\s+.*', '', df2$names), nm1)[i2]
df2
#                  names
#1                 Clark
#2 Micheal United States
#3          Sara England
#4          Laurie Lance
#5           Vivek India
```

Comment: HI, although I have already got answer by another approach but while I am using your's I am get a warning message `invalid factor level, NA generated` at this line `df2$names[i2] <- paste(sub('\\s+.*', '', df2$names), nm1)[i2]`. Reason might be because `df2$names[i2]` is factor class while `paste(sub('\\s+.*', '', df2$names), nm1)[i2]` is character class so I did `df2$names[i2] <- as.factor(paste(sub('\\s+.*', '', df2$names), nm1)[i2])` as well but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Looper I assumed that the columns are `character` in my solution.  You can convert to `character` class before doing it. i.e. `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character); df2$names <- as.character(df2$names)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the gsub function which could replace pattern and loop through the title dataframe.

```
title <- data.frame(Name = c("Ind", "USA", "UK"), corrected_Name = c("India", "United States", "United Kingdom"))
    names <- c("Clark", "Michael USA")

    for(i in 1: nrow(title)){
        gsub(title$Name[i], replacement = title$corrected_Name[i], x = names)
    }
```